# Admob ads doesn't show on some android phones

Tags: java, android, admob

My Interestitial ad and NativeExpressAd doesn't show on a few phones, I have tested on few types of phones and it worked on: Nexus 6 android 6.0.1, xperia z3 compact android 4.4.3, emulator android 6.0, xperia j5
but it doesnt work on: Xiaomi Redmi Note 2 android 5.0 and lg l5 custom rom android 6.0.
This is code of InterstitialAd:

```
interestitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
        interestitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad));
        AdRequest adReq = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        interestitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                interestitialAd.show();
            }
        });
        interestitialAd.loadAd(adReq);
```

I was considering that it could be fault of height and width but when interstitalAd doesn't need to specify AdSize.
Ye, all phones had internet connection.

Comment: Did you see the logcat output on those devices? is your onAdLoaded() called ?
are you sure that when the onAdLoaded() callback is called, you are still on that activity?

Comment: On logcat i had "ad not loaded, error code 2"

Comment: On those devices that ads don't work, are you sure that date and time are set properly?

Comment: Yes, it's set to automatic

Comment: For more, Galaxy j5 don't have any Google account logged, and Google services arę not updated, but on this Galaxy j5 ad is showing

Comment: "Xiaomi Redmi Note 2 android 5.0 and lg l5 custom rom android 6.0" Both of them have a custom rom? did you check if they have some kind of ad blocker or something like that?

Comment: Xiaomi have miui (like all xiaomi) ads is showing in other apps, lg l5 don't have any adblocker. My app is not published yet.

Comment: last ideas... although you say you have internet connection, can you navigate through internet on those devices? are you on data connection or wi fi? do you have the latest library (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1) set on your project?. did you try creating another ad unit on admob?

Comment: 1. Other things that need internet connection in my app are working properly
2. Tried on both.
3. Yes.
4. Yes.

Comment: I have read a lot of threads here and i tried all found solutions, and it doesn't help